# Array of objects from object with array value

Tags: javascript

I have the array below:

```
[{title: [1, 2], subcategory: "x", category: "y"},
{title: [3, 4], subcategory: "x", category: "y"}]
```

How can I covert it to array below?:

```
[{title: 1, subcategory: "x", category: "y"},
{title: 2, subcategory: "x", category: "y"},
{title: 3, subcategory: "x", category: "y"},
{title: 4, subcategory: "x", category: "y"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.flatMap`.

```js
const input = [{
    title: [1, 2],
    subcategory: "x",
    category: "y"
  },
  {
    title: [3, 4],
    subcategory: "x",
    category: "y"
  }
];

const output = input.flatMap((item) => item.title.map((title) => ({
  title,
  subcategory: item.subcategory,
  category: item.category
})));
console.log(output);
```